# can i open flags page on android version 2.3.4

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

I have been searching for a way to stop auto refresh. My browser sometimes won't open pages all the way. It is very jumpy. And sometimes it just shuts off. I have a LG l75c Optimus Zip android phone

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should get a good browser. Google Chrome or [Mozilla Firefox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.mozilla.firefox) are some examples.

If the problem is still there go to the settings or the browser you use and disable Javascript. This will stop auto-refresh but will also prevent any interactive content on the websites to run.